# '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[1].(2)'

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, prism

I have no clue what's the exception trying to say,i was searching in the forum but still i couldn't figure it out,so posting my question here.

Here is my xaml

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Grid.RowSpan="3"
        Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonContainer}">
    <Button Name="btnSubjectSearch"
            MinWidth="25"
            Width="25"
            Height="25"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Click="btnSubjectSearch_Click"
            Visibility="{Binding SelectedProgram.IsProgramSelected, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"
            Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}">
                <Image Source="../Resources/blue_plus.png" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Button>
    <Button Name="btnRemoveSubject"
            MinWidth="25"
            Width="25"
            Height="25"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}"
            Click="btnRemoveSubject_Click">
                <Image Source="../Resources/blue_minus.png" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

This my code behind

```
 private void btnSubjectSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Button)
        {
            **Application.Current.MainWindow.IsEnabled = false; //It throwing exception here**
            (Application.Current.MainWindow as dynamic).ProcessWindowCloseability(false);
            ShowPopup((Button)sender);
            Model.SubjectSearchCommand.Execute(null);
        }
```

[image: btnSubjectSearch]

when i click the "+" button it suppose to pop the window and show the list of subject but it throws exception at "Application.Current.MainWindow.IsEnabled = false;".

Please someone guide me the right path and thanks in advance

Comment: if you are already in the MainWindow, why dont you set IsEnabled by this.IsEnabled = False?

Comment: are you sure exception is from that line and not the line below with your "dynamic" cast? Try to comment the `IsEnabled = false` line and see if the exception still occurs.

Comment: @Viv, am sure its throwing exception at IsEnabled=false,when i comment it try to pop up the window but it freeze.

Comment: @Usher@did you find the solution??